# Repeating until done

Tags: python, repeat, goto

So Ive got this code and I want to make it repeat itself until the user makes his username not start with a symbol or number.

```
  name=name.capitalize()
    print(name)
    surname= input("surname")
    surname=surname.capitalize()
    print(surname)
    password= input("password")
    username= input("username")
    first_char = username[0]
    if first_char.isalpha():
        print('done')
    else: print('username must start with a letter')
```

Comment: You can use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using python 3.8, you can use the `:=` operator for a nice way to write this:

```
while not (username := input("username: "))[0].isalpha():
    print('username must start with a letter')
# do stuff
```

Otherwise your choices are going to be:

(a) Repeat a line of code

```
username = input("username: ")
while not username[0].isalpha():
    print('username must start with a letter')
    username = input("username: ")
# do stuff
```

or (b) Use an infinite look with a `break`:

```
while True:
    username = input("username: ")
    if username[0].isalpha():
        break
    print('username must start with a letter')
# do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this code, but it seems like all you need is a simple while loop like so:

```
surname = input("surname")
while not surname[0].isalpha():
    print("surname must start with a letter")
    surname = input("surname")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close:

```py
name = input("Name:").capitalize()
print(name)
surname = input("Surname:").capitalize()
password = input("Password:")
username = input("Username:")
while not username[0].isalpha():
print('Done')
```

Alternative:

```py
name, surname, password, username = input("Name:").capitalize(), input('Surname:').capitalize(), input('Password'), input('Username')
while not username[0].isalpha():
        print('Username must start with a letter')
print('Done')
```